# learning kotlin with a system of lower specs for android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm, android-room

i have been learning kotlin for android apps at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp for some time now, but i discovered that my computer specs is lower to android studio requirement. can i continue the lesson without android studio?

i have downloaded the android studio anyway and readyboosted my system with external flash drives but the android studio still did not work fine.

Comment: Seeing as you already have evidence yourself that Android Studio is not working great on your system, I think you have answered your own question 

Comment: It’s possible to use a text editor to modify your code, and compile it using gradle on the command terminal. It’s just not practical because you will spend inordinate amounts of time browsing various library documentation to find the packages and names of classes and functions since you won’t have the auto-complete from the IDE. And also you’ll have to keep compiling it manually to find your syntax and spelling errors.

Comment: You shouldn’t need the 8GB if you aren’t running a device emulator. A 4GB system is probably enough, and you can test on a real device instead of an emulator.

Comment: I think Tenfour gave you the right answer, the only alternative I could think of is the Intellij Idea Community edition, which can run Kotlin and Gradle but IDK how much you would have to tinker by yourself. There are things that can alleviate your work: Android Studio can be configured to work offline. Close other programs, Skype? Slack? Discord? Anything that runs on startup. Don't use the emulator, plug-in a physical device.

Comment: Here's how you can configure it for a low-spec machine: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#low_memory but there will be limits to what you can do!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay here is the how started learning android development in back 2019. In 2019 android studio recomended ram is  8 GB but Here is my PC specification 4GB ram dual core processor and 500 GB HDD . I know it make me so frastrated back then but every problem have solution  i solved my problem using changing OS when in 2019 I'm using Windows that take more space In PC so I switched My OS to Linux and it helped me lot I know still it's not that great experince.

Comment: As you just learning Android you can run you small apps smoothly and you can use some of chrome tabs NOTE: while using android studio please try to close other application ah you can use chrome but limit your tabs if you you increase your tabs you PC will be dead...